# show post of category in index controller codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i completely new in ci and i build a project that have index page and show posts in this page with pagination, i have menu sidebar that contain categories , i want when i click each them show posts of that category. how can change my code to that?

**home_controller**

```
class Home extends Ci_controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->model('home_model');
        $this->load->model('category_model');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }

    function index() {
        $category = $this->category_model->allCategory();
        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'index.php/home/index/page/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->home_model->countall();
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4;

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $posts = $this->home_model->all($config['per_page'], $page);
        $setting = $this->home_model->setting('about');
        $pagination = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->template->load('home', array('posts' => $posts, 'pagination' => $pagination, 'category' => $category, 'setting' => unserialize($setting['value'])));
    }
}
```

**home_model**

```
class Home_model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function allPost() {
        $all = $this->db->get('posts')->result_array();
        $data_send = array();
        foreach ($all as $key => $value) {
            $data = array();
            $category = $this->db->get_where('catpost', array('post_id' => $value['post_id']))->result_array();
            $data['id'] = $value['post_id'];
            $data['title'] = $value['title'];
            $data['create_time'] = $value['create_time'];
            $data['content'] = $value['content'];
            $data['username'] = $value['username'];
            $data['category'] = $category;
            $data_send[] = $data;
        }

        return $data_send;
    }

    function all($limit, $start) {
        $lastpost = $this->db->select('post_id')->order_by('create_time DESC')->limit($limit, $start)->get('post')->result_array();
        $idarr = array();
        foreach ($lastpost as $key => $value) {
            $idarr[] = "'{$value['post_id']}'";
        }

        $ids = implode(',', $idarr);
        $sql = "select tbl_post.post_id, tbl_category.name, tbl_post.title, tbl_post.content, tbl_post.create_time, tbl_post.author_id, tbl_user.username from `tbl_category` join `tbl_post_category` on `tbl_post_category`.`category_id`=`tbl_category`.`category_id` join `tbl_post` on `tbl_post`.`post_id`=`tbl_post_category`.`post_id` join tbl_user on tbl_user.user_id=tbl_post.author_id where tbl_post.post_id in($ids) ORDER BY tbl_post.post_id DESC";
        $allpost = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
        $posts = array();
        foreach ($allpost as $key => $value) {
            $postid = $value['post_id'];
            if (array_key_exists($postid, $posts)) {
                $posts[$postid]['category'] .= ",{$value['name']}";
            } else {
                $posts[$postid] = array(
                    'post_id' => $postid,
                    'title'   => $value['title'],
                    'content' => $value['content'],

                    'create_time' => $value['create_time'],

                    'username' => $value['username'],
                    'category' => $value['name']);
            }
        }
        return $posts;
    }

    function setting($name = NULL) {
        $ret = NULL;
        if ($name != NULL) {
            $this->db->where('name', $name);
            $ret = $this->db->get('setting')->result_array()[0];
        } else {
            $ret = $this->db->get('setting')->result_array();
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    function countall() {
        Return $this->db->count_all('posts');
    }
}
```

**view part of category**

```
<?php
foreach($category as $key => $value){
    $name='category['.$value['name'].']';
    echo '<li><a href='.$value['name'].'>'.$value['name'].'</a></li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: When you view your HTML output source for the list, are you showing any errors? I'm also not sure what the purpose of the $name= is.